# How to include count equal to 0 on this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

My query

```
select state,count(*) from crm_lead group by state;
```

which return

```
state   count
done    794
open    560
pending 3
draft   8
cancel  1
```

but sometime when I have no 'cancel' task in my table

```
state   count
done    794
open    560
pending 4
draft   8
```

I would like to include count = 0 in the result, what is the best query ?

Comment: Do you have another table which contains all state names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.STATE , 
        COALESCE(b.count, 0) AS Count
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'done' AS STATE
        UNION
        SELECT 'open' AS STATE
        UNION
        SELECT 'pending' AS STATE
        UNION
        SELECT 'draft' AS STATE
        UNION
        SELECT 'cancel' AS STATE
    ) a LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  STATE , 
                count(*) AS count
        FROM    crm_lead
        GROUP BY STATE
    ) b ON a.STATE = b.STATE
```

Comment: To form a set from rows without minding duplicates use `UNION ALL`. Doesn't matter much with just five rows, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this, if you only want to be sure that cancel is in the list:

```
select coalesce(t.state, const.state) as state, coalesce(t.cnt, const.cnt) as cnt
from (select state, count(*) as cnt
      from crm_lead
      group by state
     ) t full outer join
     (select 'cancel' as state, 0 as cnt
     ) const
     on t.state = const.state
```

This might be handy if the list of states is long or if you only want to be sure that one particular value is included.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler with a [`VALUES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html) expression:

```
SELECT a.state, COALESCE(b.ct, 0) AS ct
FROM (VALUES('done'), ('open'), ('pending'), ('draft'), ('cancel')) a (state)
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT state, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   crm_lead
   GROUP  BY state
 ) b USING (state);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsonb = array();
foreach($em as $k => $v) {  
    $q = "
        SELECT  a.STATE , 
        COALESCE(b.count, 0) AS Count
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'done' AS STATE
        UNION
        SELECT 'open' AS STATE
        UNION
        SELECT 'pending' AS STATE
        UNION
        SELECT 'draft' AS STATE
        UNION
        SELECT 'cancel' AS STATE
    ) a LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  STATE , 
                count(*) AS count
        FROM    crm_lead
        WHERE (create_date, create_date) OVERLAPS ('2012-{$nn}-01'::DATE, '2012-{$nn}-{$num}'::DATE)
        GROUP BY STATE
    ) b ON a.STATE = b.STATE
        ";
        $result = retrieve($q);

        $jsona = array();
        $values = array();
        $ev = array();
        foreach($result as $key => $val) {
            $ev[] = $val['count'];
        }

    $jsonb[] = array("label" => $v,"values" =>$ev);
}

$jsona[] = array("label" => array(done,open,pending,draft,cancel),"values" => $jsonb);
```

this is a completed code to contruct a JSON object to be returned to the JavaScript.
ps. this code included some custom functions which are not important, you may guess the values of them.