# Turn a number (string) in JSON object to int

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

This is a line of json_encode function in PHP

```
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($jsona).')';
```

that return

```
jQuery183022578700515441597_1353992348618([{"label":["done","open","pending","draft","cancel"],"values":[{"label":"August","values":["175","32","1","0","0"]},{"label":"September","values":["450","130","1","0","1"]},{"label":"October","values":["150","396","1","5","0"]},{"label":"November","values":["0","0","0","3","0"]}]}])
```

And I get them by JS (jQuery)

```
    $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/_state.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                dataCharset: 'jsonp',
                success: function (data) {
console.log(data);
    }
});
```

But all the number contained in returned JSON turned into Strings (Don't know why?).

How could I convert them to Integer for example;

```
{
      'label': ['done', 'open', 'pending', 'draft', 'cancel'],
      'values': [
      {
        'label': 'Sept',
        'values': [20, 40, 15, 5,2]
      }, 
      {
        'label': 'Oct',
        'values': [30, 10, 45, 10]
      }, 
      {
        'label': 'Nov',
        'values': [38, 20, 35, 17]
      }
      ]
      }
```

Comment: If they are printed as strings, then they were strings in PHP to begin with. Where is `$jsona` coming from?

Comment: As loganfsmyth says. So things need fixing in PHP not javascript.

Comment: $jsona comes from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576402/how-to-include-count-equal-to-0-on-this-query/13577879#13577879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in `$jsona` must be strings.  If you are using PHP 5.3, you can use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` as the second argument which will cast strings as integers when appropriate, but be careful with that option.

Comment: That's wonderful answer, use this constants fix every number strings in the JSON array.